# Bootstrap table, unable to load data from PHP file

Tags: php, json, html-table, bootstrap-table

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I want to fill a bootstrap table using a php file as source. Here is my code:

```
<table id="non_conformites" data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="date">Date</th>
        <th data-field="conciergerie">Conciergerie</th>
        <th data-field="utilisateur">Utilisateur</th>
        <th data-field="createur">Créateur</th>
        <th data-field="demande">Demande liée</th>
        <th data-field="domaine">Domaine</th>
        <th data-field="gravite">Gravité</th>
        <th data-field="statut">Statut</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#non_conformites').bootstrapTable({
            url:'data_ga.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is what my php file echo (I use json_encode() in order to display the right format):

```
[
    {
        "date": "2017-11-15 09:21:12",
        "conciergerie": "xx_easywhere",
        "utilisateur": "99XX01",
        "createur": "1",
        "demande": "xx_easywhere_15112017_Gard_1",
        "domaine": null,
        "gravite": "0",
        "statut": "3"
    },
    ...more data...
    {
        "date": "2017-11-16 17:07:43",
        "conciergerie": "xx_easywhere",
        "utilisateur": "99XX01",
        "createur": "",
        "demande": "xx_easywhere_16112017_Lava_5",
        "domaine": "test_maj",
        "gravite": "1",
        "statut": "2"
    }
]
```

But nothing is displayed in my table. Actually, I know that my php file is never visited, because if it is, it should create some debug txt files, and it's not the case.
When I put the data above directly inside the  and use it as a source for my table, it works.
So I'm probably not using my php source properly. If you have any clue about what I'm doing wrong, I'm more than interested :)

Comment: Your code does not contain anything that will allow you to import data from the array? Are we missing a file?

Comment: well I thought the array was provided by the php script (I found many examples of bootstrap using php file). But anyway, when I replace url: 'data_ga.php' by 'test.json' with my data in the test.json file, I don't get any result neither

Comment: Even if you would get data from the PHP or .JSON file. Your code does not contain anything processing that data. So it doesn't know where to put that data.

Comment: sry I forgot to specify that i was using the Bootstrap Table extension
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/
with the extension, my data should be prossessed

Comment: You are missing pieces of code. Literally follow those instructions. [Instructions](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage-via-data-attributes)

Comment: First off all you can add a data-url directly into the table. data-url="data1.json". If you want to do this through Javascript you have to set the table headers to the correct values like [so](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage-via-javascript).

Comment: since I tried a lot of things to make it work, I mixed indeed declaration of attribute in the table and pieces of javascript. I've already tried to follow the instructions for bootstrap table extension but none of the explained methods worked

Comment: Well does that plugin support the version of bootstrap you are running? Or is the plugin still active and being developed?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap v3.3.7 and the plugin has been created for bootstrap 3. I can run my bootstrap-table with a js variable that contains my value, so the plugin seems to work. Still impossible to run my bootstrap-table with a external json source

Comment: have you tried a different method? Like getting the data from the .json file, putting it into a variable and then doing the same as you did with: " I can run my bootstrap-table with a js variable that contains my value"

Comment: it's what I finally did and it works. But I found this solution quite ugly, so I wasn't satisfied.
And guess what... I just made it work with my php file !
<table id="non_conformites" data-toggle="table" data-url="data_ga.php"> provides me a bootstrap-table. So I'm finally not using js. I'll try to figure out what i made different than before, because, for now, it's a complete mystery. thx anyway for helping me !